# Going through on a unsorted array, distance between elements

Tags: arrays, quicksort, binary-search, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

Advice?

Given an unsorted array and the number of elements, for each element i have to print the number of elements between itself and the farest element in the array that is smaller than him, if there are not numbers -1

Example:

Input:
10 6 10 3 9 15
Output:
3  1  1 -1 -1 -1

I already did it, but my professor told it can be done much more EFFICIENT, of course im actually doing o(n^2). Divide and Conquer?, Binary Search?

My solution:

```
public void MedidaMolestia(int A[], int  N)
    {
    int i=0,  temp=0, k=N-1, j=0;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        temp = A[i];

        for(j=N-1;j>i ; j--)
        {
            if(A[j]<temp)
            break;
        }

        if(i==j)
            System.out.print(-1 + " ");

        else 
            System.out.print((j-i)-1 + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `3 1 2 -1 -1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question completely and your code and your sample output seems to be doing different things if understand your question correctly. Please explain with clear examples

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff, I can suggest some asymptotic improvement using a little dynamic programming:-

1. Use quicksort to get indices of each element in the sorted version of array.  Takes O(n log n). for your example, it should be :-

   ```
   sindex = [3 1 3 0 5 2] ( since sorted array is 3 6 9 10 10 15)
   ```
2. You need to fill an array B such that B[i] stores the 1st occurence from the rightmost of an index that is less than i. do as follows:-

   ```
   Initialize B to [N, N,...]
   filledpos = N;
   for j = N-1 to 0 inclusive
       if(sindex[j] < filledpos) do 
       for i = sindex[j] to filledpos - 1 inclusive 
       // like if you find the 3rd smallest element fill B[4],.. B[filledpos]
          B[i] = j
       filledpos = sindex[j]
   ```

   For your example B = [2 2 3 3 5 5]. takes O(n) worst case
3. Now you know the position of the rightmost elem < i. do the foll(takes O(n))

   ```
   for i = 0 to N-1
      print i - B[sindex[i]]
   ```